# Flutter / Firebase Messaging. : Not pushing notification when I run my App on release mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am computer programming student and who is making mobile app with flutter.

I am having some issue on notification, when I run my app on Debug mode, everything is working fine.

However when I run my app on the release mode with  " flutter run --release " this command,

My app is not getting notification. I am pushing the notification with Firebase messagings package.

What I find in another programmer`s code was adding application.registerForRemoteNotifications()  code on my AppDelegate.swift, but actually there Is no difference...

How can I fix this problem ?

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications() 
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

In summary, on debug mode everything is working fine, however on the release mode , its not getting the notification.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you follow iOS integration section of the fcm plugin? Did you add APN keys of your app to firebase console?

Comment: Yes I did everything, so as I told you it is perfectly working on debug mode.

Comment: Just for try can you send a notification for the firebase console and check?

Comment: @DaegilPyo this may sound weird to you, but what is the name of your firebase app ? does it contains words like dev or test

Comment: @HasilT No, I don't have that words in my App name..

Answer (score 0):

This is  a common issue amongst all flutter developers since most of us use VS Code
or other light-weight IDEs to develop rather than using android studio.
The easy and straight forward way of signing your application is as said in the [Google Developers Website](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth).

Just head to your IDE terminal and type `cd android` and then type `./gradlew signingReport` ensure that your "google-services.json" file does include your unique SHA1 Key, which you can get by heading to your
`C->Program Files->Java->javaversion->bin`
then run your terminal in this directory and write the command

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore"
```

for windows. this shall show your SHA1 key, head towards google firebase console and sign your projects.